# Only the first MQTT message from ESP32 to AWS IoT Core succeeds – what am I missing?

Tags: mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, arduino-esp32

I am using an ESP32-CAM to capture an image and transmit that image in Base64 to AWS IoT Core.

I'm using Pubsubclient, and the connection is sound.

When I compile my code, the first message transmits successfully and is complete. Subsequent messages are truncated, even after a reset of the device. The only message that transmits successfully is the first message upon compile and flash.

Here is my publishMessage() function:

```
void publishMessage() {
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }  

  char *input = (char *)fb->buf;

//AWS Lambda Actions need base64 encoded data, jsonified
  char output[base64_enc_len(3)];
  String image;
  for (int i=0;i<fb->len;i++) {
    base64_encode(output, (input++), 3);
    if (i%3==0) image += String(output);
  }
  
  String imageFile = "{\"image\":\""+image+"\"}";
  uint32_t fbLen=imageFile.length();

  if(!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to AWS IOT");

    while (!client.connect(THINGNAME)) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);
    }

    if (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.println("AWS IoT Timeout!");
      return;
    }
  }

  boolean res = client.beginPublish(AWS_IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC, fbLen, false);
  Serial.println("publish began " + String(res));

  for (uint32_t n=0;n<fbLen;n=n+2048) {
    String str = "";
    if (n+2048<fbLen) {
      str = imageFile.substring(n, n+2048);
      client.write((uint8_t*)str.c_str(), 2048);
    }
    else if (fbLen%2048>0) {
      uint32_t remainder = fbLen%2048;
      str = imageFile.substring(n, n+remainder);
      client.write((uint8_t*)str.c_str(), remainder);
    }
    Serial.println(String(n));
  }  

  Serial.println("publish written " + String(res));

  res = client.endPublish();
  Serial.println("publish ended " + String(res));

  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am handling memory allocation properly, but I suspect this may be where the problem lies.

The truncated message contains a significant portion of the image, but there seems to be white space added in, and, of course, it is missing the closing quotation marks & curly brace.

[image: Truncated message]

What am I missing?

I used setBufferSize to accommodate the total message size. I tried chunking the image into 1 byte chunks as well as 64000 byte chunks. The same result occurs. I have searched for any information as to why the initial message succeeds, but all subsequent messages fail. That's the most perplexing part of the issue.

Comment: is that an sqs message? if so there's a limit on how big the messages can be. why not upload to s3?

Comment: Sure your loop code, are you running the MQTT client loop?

Comment: `String imageFile = "{"image":""+image+""}";` does not look like it would compile to me? (and you don't use `imageFile` in the publish code, other than for the length?).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It's an MQTT message. I was having trouble with credentials uploading to s3, but for some reason IoT was easier. 

Yes, running client.loop() in my loop code.

I lost my escape character when I copied the code. Rookie mistake. Edited original post.

Comment: Still would not compile because `imageFile` is a `String`, not the `const char *__restrict` that `strncpy` expects. This makes it difficult to see what you are really doing (it appears that you are copying [the same data](https://wokwi.com/projects/380064890287349761) into `output` multiple times). Note that you can avoid much of this by passing the data directly (use [`int write (payload, length)`](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api#write2) and split things into 3+ writes - `{/"image/":/"` then `image` then `/"}`).

Comment: I'm sorry for my neglect in copying my code. I'm not using strncpy, but substring. This seems to identify part of the problem: https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/issues/791 That is, pubsubclient uses a uint16_t for the payload length, but my payload length is a larger integer. I changed pubsubclient.cpp & pubsubclient.h per the recommendation, and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/issues/791

PubSubClient's buildHeader function takes a uint16_t payload length. This restricts payloads to 64kb or less.

Edits to the function definitions for both buildHeader and write in PubSubClient.h and PubSubClient.cpp allow for larger payloads.

Before:

```
boolean write(uint8_t header, uint8_t* buf, uint16_t length);
size_t buildHeader(uint8_t header, uint8_t* buf, uint16_t length);
```

After:

```
boolean write(uint8_t header, uint8_t* buf, uint32_t length);
size_t buildHeader(uint8_t header, uint8_t* buf, uint32_t length);
```